# How can I access Azure document db node js TriggerType definition?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I get TriggerType undefined when the following trigger is uploaded to an azure document collection:

```
'mytriggerTrigger': {
    id: 'triggerid',
    serverScript: function Foo() {
        // code omitted
    },
    triggerType: TriggerType.Pre,
    triggerOperation : TriggerOperation.Create
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import `DocumentBase` object, then you can access these properties.

```
var documentdb = require('documentdb'),
DocumentClient = documentdb.DocumentClient,
DocumentBase = documentdb.DocumentBase;

'mytriggerTrigger': {
    id: 'triggerid',
    serverScript: function Foo() {
        // code omitted
    },
    triggerType: DocumentBase.TriggerType.Pre,
    triggerOperation : DocumentBase.TriggerOperation.Create
}
```